# Showing a recursively defined sequence is convergent using Banach fixed-point theorem

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, fixed-point-theorems

I recently stumbled across an interesting question, in which we need to show a recursively defined sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ in $\mathbb{R}$ defined as follows

$$
x_0 = 4 , \quad x_{n+1}=\ln\left(3-\frac{x_n}{2}\right) \quad \text{for} \ \ \  n \ge 1
$$

is convergent using the Banach Fixed-Point Theorem.

I am familiar with how to show a function is convergent using the Banach Fixed-Point Theorem given, but I haven't necessarily seen it be used on a recursively defined sequence. I'd assume you could use generating functions, but is there an easier way?

I would be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here are some possible steps.

- Prove that $T : [0, 4] \to [0, 4]$, with $T(x) = \ln \left( 3 - \tfrac x 2 \right)$, is a well-defined function. (You'll need to prove that if $x \in [0, 4]$, then $T(x) \in [0, 4]$ too.)
- Prove that $T$ is a contraction, with $|T(x_1) - T(x_2)| \leq \tfrac 1 2 |x_1 - x_2|$ for all $x_1, x_2 \in [0, 4]$. (I suggest you do this by showing that $|T'(x)| \leq \frac 1 2$ for all $x \in [0, 4]$.)
- Use the fact that $T$ is a contraction to deduce that the sequence defined by $x_0 = 4$ and $x_{n+1} = T(x_n)$ for $n \geq 1$ is a Cauchy sequence.
- Explain why $[0, 4]$ is a complete metric space.
- Conclude that the sequence $x_n$, being Cauchy, is convergent.

Bullet points 3 and 5 use ideas from the proof of the Banach fixed point theorem. So you can view this solution strategy as an "application" of the Banach fixed point theorem.

Answer (score 1):

The Banach Fixed-Point Theorem shows that if a map $T\colon X\to X$ is a *contraction* then it has a unique fixed point, provided that $X$ is a non-empty complete metric space. For $T$ to be a contraction there must be a constant $K$ with $d(T(x),T(y))\leq K.d(x,y)$ for all $x,y \in X$.

The theorem is proved by picking an arbitrary point $x_0 \in X$, which you think of as an initial "guess" at where the fixed point is. You then consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n \geq 0}$ defined recursively by $x_{n+1} = T(x_n)$. Using the contraction condition you can show this is a Cauchy sequence and so if $X$ is complete it has a limit, say $y\in X$. The limit must satisfy
$$
T(y)=T(\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n) = \lim_{n\to \infty} T(x_n) =\lim_{n\to \infty} x_{n+1} =y,
$$
since $T$ is continuous (in fact Lipschitz continuous). The fixed point is unique because if $z_1,z_2$ are fixed points, then $d(z_1,z_2) = d(T(z_1),T(z_2))\leq K.d(z_1,z_2)$ and hence since the distance function is non-negative and $K\in (0,1)$ we must have $d(z_1,z_2)=0$ and so $z_1 =z_2$. Another way of phrasing the uniqueness part is to note that, if $z_0$ is a fixed point, then
$$
d(z_0,x_{n+1}) = d(z_0,T(x_n))= d(T(z_0),T(x_n))\leq Kd.(z_0,x_n),
$$
so by induction $d(z_0,x_n) \leq K^nd(z_0,x_0) \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, hence $y=z_0$.

Hopefully this helps in seeing how the theorem is relevant to the sequence you are given!

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the fixed point theorem is used on recursive function by finding $f$ such that $x_{n+1} = f(x_n)$.

From there, all you need to do is make sure all the necessary conditions are satisfied (in this case, contraction), and you can apply the theorem to show it's convergent.